# Specifying version from angular-ui/bootstrap via bower -> error: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, github, angular-ui-bootstrap, public-key

I trying to get a specify git commit:

```
bower install --save git@github.com:angular-ui/bootstrap.git#b72136e59211abb83643b28a61b031f1fbb524c2
```

But this command comes back with the following error:

> Permission denied (publickey)

Is there any way to avoid the installation from the public key. I don't want force all my colleague to install a key locally.

I also tried to get the master branch, but the bower file refers to the 0.12.0 version.

```
bower install --save angular-bootstrap#master
```

Thanks, Stevo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the https access.

`bower install --save https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap.git#b72136e59211abb83643b28a61b031f1fbb524c2`

Related: https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/